# Type conversion: LibraryLink mint vs. MathLink integer type

Tags: mathlink-or-wstp, librarylink

Assume the following situation: I have a *WolframLibrary* function which gets as parameter an integer tensor (which is for simplicity of rank 1) and the function should return an integer list through *MathLink*.

My question is about the used types in this function only. The start of such a function could look like the following, where I use *WolframLibrary* functions declared in `WolframLibrary.h`

```c
EXTERN_C DLLEXPORT mint func( WolframLibraryData lib, mint argc, 
                              MArgument *args, MArgument return_value)
{
  MTensor tensor_u0 = MArgument_getMTensor(args[0]);
  mint *u0 = lib->MTensor_getIntegerData(tensor_u0);    
  // ...
}
```

The full declaration of the last function is

```c
mint* (*MTensor_getIntegerData)( MTensor);
```

The array `u0` contains the linear data of our tensor. Let's say I worked with this array, I used consistently `mint` in all procedures and I want to send now the `mint *result` array back through *MathLink*.

In the *MathLink* API we have several functions for sending integer lists

```c
int MLPutInteger16List(MLINK link, short *a,int n)
int MLPutInteger32List(MLINK link, int *a,int n)
int MLPutInteger64List(MLINK link, mlint64 *a, int n)
```

Usually you just use `MLPutIntegerList` which uses the integer type of the machine. Unfortunately, since version 9 the *MathLink* integer type and the *WolframLibrary* integer type differ on my machine.

Additionally, the types used in *MathLink* seem to be completely unrelated to the *WolframLibrary* types. While I can use the types in a pure *WolframLibrary* function consistently and hopefully portable, mixing those two technologies seems not possible easily.

What I would have to do is to look up the underlying type of `mint`, which is `long` on my machine here, but `int` on the Windows machine of my colleague and probably `long long` on our Windows 7 64bit box. After that I can select the appropriate `MLPut...` function for my special system. This is not portable and I basically have to repeat all system-dependent `#ifdef`s which are already there in `mathlink.h` and friends.

**Question:** What am I missing here? There must be a portable and consistent way to cast both types.

Comment: @ToddGayley In case you missed this question. Some insight or corrections would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Just an idea without much thought put into it (sorry if I overlooked something): if you're using C++, create a *single* overloaded function that calls `MLPutInteger16List`, `MLPutInteger32List` or `MLPutInteger64List` depending on the type of arguments, then use this function.  The compiler will figure out which version of the overloaded function to call when you pass it a `mint *`, and you won't need to think about it as a user or disambiguate with lots of `#define`s and `#ifdef`s and anticipating various types ...

Answer (score 6):

What you observed is a bit unfortunate because these libraries should be easy to use together (because they're *meant* to be used together).

Here's a "workaround" that could make your life easier in certain cases.  You can use C++ instead of C and take advantage of overloaded functions.  I have a header called `mlp.h` with the following:

```c++
#include <mathlink.h>

inline int mlpPutIntegerList(MLINK link, short *a, int n) {
    return MLPutInteger16List(link, a, n);
}   

inline int mlpPutIntegerList(MLINK link, int *a, int n) {
    return MLPutInteger32List(link, a, n);
}

inline int mlpPutIntegerList(MLINK link, mlint64 *a, int n) {
    return MLPutInteger64List(link, a, n);
}

// ... similar overloaded versions for other MLPut* functions.
// might need some for long long or compiler specific types too
```

Then instead of calling one of the `MLPutIntegerList` functions explicitly, call `mlpPutIntegerList`:

```c++
mint *u0 = ...
mlpPutIntegerList(link, u0, count);
```

For as long as you can be sure that `mint` is one of `short`, `int`, or `long`, the compiler will figure out the correct overload to call, and you can use the same source code on all platforms.

One situation where this may potentially go wrong is if `mint` is not a standard integer type but something else (e.g. a `struct`).  I don't believe that this can be the case, but theoretically it's possible.  For example, `mlint64` is a `struct` on 32-bit platforms.

---

I have used this approach to connect MathLink with another library where the other library has a custom integer type that had different sizes (and different underlying types) on various platforms.

Also, this takes some work, but it's cleaner than using many `#ifdef`s and it's also more easily re-usable across projects.

Comment: Of course +1 for this nice answer. I probably prefer a C++ template solution because all code is generated at compile time and has no overhead when using it, but your overloading version is maybe easier to understand. Honestly I was hoping for an answer of someone from WRI to understand *how it meant to be used* ;-)